# Shell Scripting: Is there a way to use variable as output instead of a file for executable?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

For a command like:

```
/command -in input_filename -of output_filename
```

is it possible to use a `variable` instead of `output_filename`

I have tried redirections but that didn't work

Edit:

After reading comments and answers I feel perhaps the question is confusing. Executable expects filename for its **output**. However, I want to save that **output** in a variable.

Comment: `/command -f ${variablehere}` works fine in a script...

Comment: thanks.. I should mention that filename is output file.. check edited question

Comment: Dude, you cant keep changing the question!

Comment: Yes because looking at the wrong answers I feel the question might be confusing

Comment: @Nic3500 No, he's trying to clarify his original goal; he's looking for the equivalent of a command substitution `x=$(command -in input_filename)` but specifying the target variable as an output "filename" instead.

Comment: Something like `command -in input_filename $> x` (to make up a redirection operator `$>`) might be an interesting addition to a shell.

Comment: @chepner: <$ nice idea! It is interesting because I would think there should already be a way to re-direct output from a file pointer to a variable... hmmm.

Comment: Process substitution is very close to what you want, as `command -of >(cat)` provides a file name to `command` that, when written to, sends data to the input of `cat`. Something like `command -of >(read x)` would be close, setting `x` to (only) the first line of data written by `command`, except `x` exists only in the process created by `>(....)`, not in the shell that actually runs `command`.

Comment: See also `zsh/mapfile` in `man zshmodules`. It's the reverse of what you want: access the contents of any file via an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not specify a variable as an output file and then have it populated.

Instead, have the program write to stdout and capture it. How you do this depends on the command. Since you don't specify, here is an example with `curl`:

```
# Many programs automatically write to stdout when a file is not specified
myvar=$(curl http://stackoverflow.com)

# Many programs accept - to mean stdout for output files
myvar=$(curl -o - http://stackoverflow.com)

# Otherwise, you can often specify /dev/stdout
myvar=$(curl -o /dev/stdout http://stackoverflow.com)
```

If this isn't possible because the command doesn't have clean output, you may be forced to write it to a temporary file and read it back.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think my question was creating confusing I have again edit it. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: @muhammadharis I'm unaware of any shell that will map a variable into the file system, but your command should provide some way to write to standard output so that you can capture the result as shown here. A standard convention is to use `-` as the file name, and some file systems have an entry `/dev/stdout` which is a link to whatever file the current process is using for standard output.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Declare your variable at
# some point earlier in script
variable="somevalue.txt"

.
.
.

# Use it later in script
command -f $variable
```

Good practice, declare variable as readonly.
This way you do not accidently overwrite it's
value at some later point in script.

```
# Declare as readonly
readonly variable="somevalue"
```

Comment: well point is that I don't want to save the output of executable in a file. Therefore I am looking for a way to save output in a variable. File is output file ...

Comment: @muhammadharis So you are trying to run some command on some file, then there should be some output on the command line, and then you are trying to capture that output into a variable?

Comment: I will leave my upvote on the answer since @JabariDash did answer the original question: `is it possible to use a variable instead of output_filename`

Answer (score 0):

Save the output of a command:

```
# Capture output into variable
output="$(command -f filename)"

# Print it / do whatever you want with it
echo "$output"
```

Edit:

If the command requires this format:

```
/command -in input_filename -of output_filename
```

But, you also want to capture the contents of what goes to the output file in a variable, you can read the output file into a variable once the original command is done.

```
output="$(cat output_filename)"
```

This would come after the original command because the output file must be written before you can read it again.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think my question was creating confusing I have again edit it. Can you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but with your last comments, I guess you want this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
variable=$(./command -f $inputfile)

echo $variable
```

This will print the result output from the command.  Note that this does not store the status of the command, it stores the output text (if any).

For version 2 of your question (!):

```
/command -in input_filename -of output_filename
```

Most commands, if you do not specify -of options will send the output to STDOUT.  So use the first method above.

If you have to use that, the output must go to a file.  So read the file into a variable then, after the command is done.

```
variable=$(cat output_filename)
```

Note that you will loose the format of the file, hopefully it is a single line file.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think my question was creating confusing I have again edit it. Can you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do this using special brackets.  I believe {} and back ticks (near the 1 key) Something like

```
VAR1=${`cat /file`} but that's formatted incorrectly.
```

I can't remember the exact format which is why I'm here but doing it that way is possible if it's formatted right.